# Get JSON text from WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to get the contents of http://www.devpowerapi.com/fingerprint from a WKWebView

`evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.innerHTML")` returns `<head></head><body></body>` instead of the actual JSON

Is it possible to get the contents with a WKWebView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simplest way to do this (works for this specific case):**

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML", completionHandler: { (res, error) in
     if let fingerprint = res {
          // Fingerprint will be a string of JSON. Parse here...
          print(fingerprint)
     }
})
```

**Possibly better way to do this:**

So `.innerHTML` returns HTML, not a JSON header. JSON headers are notoriously difficult to grab with `WKWebView`, but you could try this method for that. First set:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

And then in the `WKNavigationDelegate` method:

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    let res = navigationResponse.response as! HTTPURLResponse
    let header = res.allHeaderFields
    print(header)
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when doing the first solution: `Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML'), WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=40, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=about:blank, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}`

Comment: Ah, evaludateJavaScript should be called in `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this is the correct solution but it is a solution none, the less. The request will be made in the context of the webView.

```swift
webView.evaluateJavaScript("""
var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
Httpreq.open("GET",'http://www.devpowerapi.com/fingerprint',false);
Httpreq.send(null);
Httpreq.responseText;
""",
    completionHandler: {
       (innerHTML, error) in
       print(innerHTML, error)
})
```

I'm sure you could use any of the JavaScript solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22790025/193772).